Python Text to SQL - migrating from ChatGPT to Lllam2 using LM Studio
So I have this code running in python that will take a text type of query , such as "How many customers do I have?" and it will use the below and convert to a SQL query using the prompt template with is simply a schema of the table to check, this code below runs 100% fine:
def query_maker(user_input):
    # make sql queries using LLM chain
    openaiLLM = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7, openai_api_key=api_key, cache=False)
  
    prompt_template = PromptTemplate.from_template(
        "{system_prompt} + '\n' +  {user_input}.")

    chain = LLMChain(llm=openaiLLM, prompt=prompt_template)
    
    query=chain.run({"system_prompt": query_maker_gpt_system_prompt, "user_input": user_input})
     
  return(query)

I want to now convert this to use a local LLM running on LM STUDIO as its private data and dont want it exposed to openai - my local LLM is running Llama2 and is as follows:
def query_maker(user_input):
    
     
    # Define the API endpoint
    #  for the local LLM
    api_url = "http://localhost:1234/v1/chat/completions"

    # Construct the payload for the API request
    payload = {
        "model": "TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGUF/llama-2-7b-chat.Q4_0.gguf",
        "inputs": {
            "system_prompt": query_maker_gpt_system_prompt,
            "user_input": user_input
        },
        "parameters": {
            "temperature": 0.7
        }
    }

    # Send the request to the local API
    try:
        response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload)
        response_data = response.json()

        # Extract the query from the response
        if 'choices' in response_data and response_data['choices']:
            query = response_data['choices'][0]['message']['content']
            print(query)
            return query
        else:
            return "No response from model."

    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to connect to the local model:", e)
        return "Error connecting to the model."

This is giving all kinds of errors
The console shows: [2024-04-23 22:46:10.677] [ERROR] 'messages' field is required
and the browser shows:
('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
Anyone else managed to get this right?
